# Doctrine2 Entity Custom Joining

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm new to doctrine entities but I have a user table and a role table and the roles are linked to user using bit masking. Like so

```
+----+----------+------+
| id | username | role |
+----+----------+------+
| 1  | admin    | 1022 |
+----+----------+------+

+----+------------+------------+
| id | role       | permission |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 | ROLE_ADMIN |          2 |
|  2 | ROLE_DEV   |          4 |
+----+------------+------------+
```

How do I setup my User entity class to load the `User::$roles` property so that `Symfony` can retrieve them with `User::getRoles()` function? Preferably by loading and array of the Role entity.

Equivalent to this:

```
SELECT r.* 
FROM user u 
   LEFT JOIN role r 
   ON (u.role & r.permission) 
WHERE u.id = :id
```

Comment: Bit fields are a horrible way to store data, not least because masking isn't sargable (indexes are B-trees based on complete values, rather than individual bits) and referential integrity cannot be enforced. If you absolutely *must* do it, then at very least consider MySQL's [`SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/set.html) data type (which is implemented as a bit field beneath the surface, but provides a human-friendly API through which bits are addressed by name; and one could also use [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) in join criteria).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The roles can be stored in some class, for example (treat code below as pseudo code because):

```
class Roles 
{
    static private $roles = array(
        'ROLE_ADMIN',
        'ROLE_DEV'
    );

    public static function getRoleName($index)
    {
        return (isset($roles[$value]) ? $roles[$value] : false);
    }

    public static function getIndex($value)
    {
        return array_search($value, $roles);
    }
}
```

This can be generated somewhere if you need it from database (look at Life cycle events in doctrine)

Then you can define your custom mapping doctrine type let's say "role"
[Custom mapping types](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/custom-mapping-types.html)

Something like this (not tested, and you have to make some checks to not overflow integer size):

```
class RoleType extends Type
{
    const ROLE_TYPE = 'role'; 

    public function getSQLDeclaration(array $fieldDeclaration, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return 'INT'; //your sql type
    }

    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        // ensure to requrie your role class in bootstrap
        $roles = array();
        $index = 0;
        while ($value) {
           $role = $value & 1;
           if ($role && $roleName = Roles::getRoleName($index)) {
               $roles[] = $roleName;
           }
           if ($roleName === false) {
             break;
           }

           $value = $value >> 2;
           ++$index;
        }

        return $roles;
    }

    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        $roleValue = 0;
        foreach ($value as $roleName) {
            $role = Roles::getIndex($roleName);
            if ($role !== false) {
                $roleValue |= pow(2, $role);
            }
        }

        return $roleValue;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return self::ROLE_TYPE;
    }
}
```

And to register type in Symfony [Registering Custom Mapping Types](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/dbal.html#registering-custom-mapping-types)

**Anyway I think the best option is to make relation between user and roles.**